# Did the Jesuit missions in New Spain coerce native labor?

Tags: slavery, spanish-empire, mexico, labour-history, jesuits

Several Catholic orders operated missions in colonial Mexico; Dominicans, Franciscans, and Jesuits (before their expulsion) all had their own strategies. Alejandro Murguía in *The Medicine of Memory* differentiates them thus (the bolding is mine):

> The Jesuits are teachers and scholars; the Franciscans, missionaries and colonizers. Whereas the Jesuits **oppose enslavement of the Indians**, the Franciscans are enemies of the flesh and firm believers in punishment.

Is this claim true? [Jesuits in South America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesuit_reduction) used indigenous labor that is easily compared to enslavement, just as the Franciscans did in the California missions (both examples of *reducción*). Were local conditions different and Murguía correct, or did Jesuit missions in New Spain also coerce native labor?

Comment: I read this and am more confused than ever: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_American_name_controversy

Comment: I think that in order to get a reasonable answer, you need to be more specific about what is meant by "coerce"?  There's a broad range between "tithe to the church or you'll go to Hell" and outright enslavement.  And of course the Church was certainly using variations on the first in Europe...